# ActiveRecord callback after_save not really called after saved

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

Having this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :execute_after_save

  def execute_after_save
    Kernel.puts "Actual object still not saved" if changed?
  end
end
```

The `Kernel.puts` sentence should be called **never** because after the object is *saved* it is not *changed*.

```
1.9.3p286 :003 > u = User.create!(:name => "Wadus Name")
Actual object still not saved
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Wadus Name"> 
1.9.3p286 :004 > u.changed?
 => false 
1.9.3p286 :004 > u.name = "Other Name"
 => "Other Name" 
1.9.3p286 :005 > u.changed?
 => true 
1.9.3p286 :006 > u.save!
Actual object still not saved
 => true 
1.9.3p286 :007 > u.changed?
 => false
```

See all the `Actual object still not saved` sentences that shouldn't be there.

I was expecting that the `after_save` callback is actually called *after the object is saved*.

This situation is turning me crazy with some combinations of `dirty objects` and `callbacks` that I have to do.

Comment: Code that reproduces the issue: https://gist.github.com/fguillen/4771248

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's after save but before commit.

`after_commit` might be something you're looking for.